# cucumber AmbiguousStepDefinitionsException Java

Tags: java, regex, automation, cucumber

I'm getting an AmbiguousStepDefinitionsException with the following case, I don't understand how to solve this problem. Please help!

scenario

```
  Scenario Outline: Testing the price ordering filter
    When the <priceOrder> filter is clicked
    Then prices are ordered by <priceOrder>
    Examples:
    |  priceOrder |
    |  ascending  |
    |  descending |

  Scenario Outline: Testing the stars hotel filter
    When the <star> stars hotel filter is clicked
    Then all hotels are <star> stars
    Examples:
    |  star  |
    |    1   |
    |    2   |
    |    3   |
    |    4   |
    |    5   |
```

step file

```
    @When("^the (.*?) filter is clicked$")
    public void thePriceOrderFilterIsClicked(String priceOrder) {
        hotelPage.activatePriceFilter(priceOrder);
    }

    @When("^the (\\d+) stars hotel filter is clicked$")
    public void theStarStarsHotelFilterIsClicked(int star) {
        hotelPage.activateStarsFilter(String.valueOf(star));
    }

    @Then("^all hotels are (\\d+) stars$")
    public void allHotelsAreStarStars(int star) throws InterruptedException {
        hotelPage.checkHotelStars(String.valueOf(star));
    }
```

error

```
cucumber.runtime.AmbiguousStepDefinitionsException: ✽.When the 5 stars hotel filter is clicked(hotelSearches.feature:16) matches more than one step definition:
  ^the (.*?) filter is clicked$ in HotelSearchesSteps.thePriceOrderFilterIsClicked(String)
  ^the (\d+) stars hotel filter is clicked$ in HotelSearchesSteps.theStarStarsHotelFilterIsClicked(int)
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: This pattern `^the (.*?) filter is clicked$` will match both scenario's. You could perhaps make the first pattern less generic  `the (\w+) filter is clicked`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern that you use `This pattern ^the (.*?) filter is clicked$` matching until the first occurrence of filter which will match both scenario's.

If you want the first scenario matched `the <priceOrder> filter is clicked` and the `<priceOrder>` can be for example ascending or descending, you could match 1+ word characters `(\w+)`, only lowercase chars `([a-z]+)` or use an alternation `(ascending|descending)` to make it specific.

For example keeping the capturing group:

```
the (\w+) filter is clicked
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the gherkin steps and the correspondent step definiton

1)

```
From:  When the <priceOrder> filter is clicked
To:    When the "<priceOrder>" filter is clicked
```

The step def will be:

```
@When("^the \"([^\"]*)\" filter is clicked$")
public void theFilterIsClicked(String arg0)  {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
}
```

2)

```
From: Then prices are ordered by <priceOrder>
To:   Then prices are ordered by "<priceOrder>"
```

The step def will be:

```
@Then("^prices are ordered by \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void pricesAreOrderedBy(String arg0)  {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
}
```

3)

```
From:  When the <star> stars hotel filter is clicked
To:    When the "<star>" stars hotel filter is clicked
```

The step def will be:

```
@When("^the \"([^\"]*)\" stars hotel filter is clicked$")
public void theStarsHotelFilterIsClicked(String arg0) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
}
```

4)

```
From: Then all hotels are <star> stars
To:   Then all hotels are "<star>" stars
```

The step def will be:

```
@Then("^all hotels are \"([^\"]*)\" stars$")
public void allHotelsAreStars(String arg0)  {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
}
```